# Is It possible to get the MySQL Tracking Report?

Tags: php, mysql

From my PHP, I'm trying to obtain the tracking reports for my database tables. I've tried searching this online but found no results

Basically,

I've got a table in a schema, and turned on version tracking, so every update, create, drop, insert will be logged..

Now, Is it possible to obtain the data from PHP? I've tried the following:

```
$Query = $DB->prepare("Tracking report for table `betalock`.`tblkeys`");
    $Query->execute();
    $Result_Set = $Query->get_result();
    $Arr = $Result_Set->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This has failed, and after searching. I have no alternative than to post here in the hope to get some information

Comment: what tracking are you referring to ??

Comment: I can't find a `TRACKING REPORT` command in the MySQL documentation. Are you sure this command exists?

Comment: I can see "Tracking" In my PHP Userinfterface; I've enabled tracking and it logs all my changes

Comment: and what " PHP Userinfterface" would that be ?? This is clearly something 'custom' and not native to php or mysql so you have to give us a lot more information

Comment: @Dagon My bad, time to get a coffee.. I mean Phpmyadmin User-interface

Comment: ah ok, you know that only tracks changes you make in phpmyadmim, not changes made any otehr way

Comment: @Dagon Damn, I guess it's back to triggers for the database tables to store inside a seperate table then process by PHP

Comment: there's query logging- if that's any help

Comment: @Dagon The problem is, i'm in the process of creating a PDFSql Reporting tool, which gathers multiple pieces of data from the database, such as StoredLogged Errors, number of schemas, number of inner tables per schema, and a view/base table count for a schema then report in a PDF Document and either save it to a seperate database OR print it off if the managers request a print out of the current database state

Comment: In this page [Change tracking](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Change_tracking) it says : Of course you can view the tracked changes. On the Tracking page a complete report is available for every version.